# Ruby PageObject Design for Similar Page Sections

Tags: ruby, angular, selenium, watir, page-object-gem

I'm using the Cheezy Page Object gem (which also means I'm using Watir, which also means I'm using Selenium). I also have the watir gem explicitly loaded.

Anyway I have a site I am modeling with the UI written in angular where there is 1 page whose contents change based on dropdown selection. The page has several sections but it is visibly the same for each dropdown choice. The only difference is the xpath locators I am using to get there (there's no unique ID on the sections).

So for example I have an xpath like `html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/**green**/div/div[1]`

and another like

```
html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/**red**/div/div[1]
```

The elements on the sections strangely all have the same ID attribute and same class name. So I've been using xpath for the elements since that appears to make it a unique locator.

Problem is there are currently seven dropdown choices each with several sections like this. And they have visibly same elements and structure (from end user perspective) but when you look at html the only difference is the locator so like this for the elements:

`html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/green/div/div[1]/**<element>**`

and another like

```
html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/red/div/div[1]/**<element>**
```

In my current design I have created one page and created page sections for each section on a page. Multiply the number of page sections with number of dropdown choices and you see it is alot.  Some of the choices do generate extra elements but there are still common elements between all sections. I also have to duplicate all of these elements across the seven different pages because the xpath is different. Is there some way for me to pass some initializer to the PageObject page_section like the type-a or type-b string and then based on that I can also choose correct xpath for all elements?

So like if I have text field like so in like a base page object page_section:

`text_field(:team, xpath: "...#{type_variable}")`

Can I do something like `section = SomePageObject.page_section_name(type_variable)`?

EDIT: Adding Page Object code per request

```
class BasePO
  include PageObject

  #Option S1 Cards
  page_section(:options_red_card, OptionRedCard, xpath: "/html/body/app-component/app-page/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/ngb-tabset/div/div/red/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div")
  page_section(:options_green_card, OptionGreenCard, xpath: "/html/body/app-component/app-page/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/ngb-tabset/div/div/green/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div")
  page_section(:options_yellow_card, OptionYellowCard, xpath: "/html/body/app-component/app-page/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/ngb-tabset/div/div/yellow/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div")

  #Detail S2 Cards
  page_section(:detail_red_card, DetailRedCard, xpath: "/html/body/app-component/app-page/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/ngb-tabset/div/div/red/div[1]/div/div/div")
  page_section(:detail_green_card, DetailGreenCard, xpath: "/html/body/app-component/app-page/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/ngb-tabset/div/div/green/div[1]/div/div/div")
  page_section(:detail_yellow_card, DetailYellowCard, xpath: "/html/body/app-component/app-page/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/ngb-tabset/div/div/yellow/div[1]/div/div/div")

end
```

EDIT2: Adding page_section content per request. All Option Cards share these elements at a minimum. Different elements in the Detail Cards but same structure as Option Cards.

```
class OptionRedCard
  include PageObject

  def field1_limit
    text_field_element(xpath: "/html/body/app-component/app-page/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/ngb-tabset/div/div/red-unit/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/red/form/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div/currency/div/input")
  end

  def field1_agg
    text_field_element(xpath: "/html/body/app-component/app-page/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/ngb-tabset/div/div/red-unit/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/red/form/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div[2]/div/currency/div/input")
  end

  def field2_limit
    text_field_element(xpath: "/html/body/app-component/app-page/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/ngb-tabset/div/div/red-unit/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/red/form/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div/currency/div/input")
  end

  def field2_agg
    text_field_element(xpath: "/html/body/app-component/app-page/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/ngb-tabset/div/div/red-unit/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/red/form/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/div/div[2]/div/currency/div/input")
  end

  def field3_limit
    text_field_element(xpath: "/html/body/app-component/app-page/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/ngb-tabset/div/div/red-unit/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/red/form/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div/currency/div/input")
  end

  def field3_agg
    text_field_element(xpath: "/html/body/app-component/app-page/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/ngb-tabset/div/div/red-unit/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/red/form/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/div/div[2]/div/currency/div/input")
  end

  def field1_agg_value
    field1_agg.attribute_value('data-value')
  end

  def field2_agg_value
    field2_agg.attribute_value('data-value')
  end

  def field3_agg_value
    field3_agg.attribute_value('data-value')
  end

end
```

Comment: [check this](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/wiki/Page-Sections)

Comment: @yudi2312 are you suggesting, even though it isn't show in the article for this specific case, to use regex for the xpath page sections and elements?

Comment: I don't think regex is going to help you in this. Correct me if I'm wrong, All sections have same elements and each element have same attributes in all sections, right?

Comment: Yes there are some choices which generate sections with extra elements but the majority are exact same section and exact same elements with same attributes

Comment: Have you tried using `visible` locator?

Comment: @yudi2312 no. You can use `visible` locator on `page_section`?

Comment: Can you post the code for your page object?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Updated OP with page object

Comment: Can you share some of the page section definitions? I am having a hard time understanding what's the functional difference between say OptionRedCard and OptionGreeenCard.

Comment: @JustinKo I can add it but the main issue was just trying to see if I could dynamically choose a page_section based off of either some parameter or something. Does seeing the elements in the page sections matter in this case?

Comment: @Bmoe, I don't know. I guess I'm still struggling to understand the page-object design as it doesn't follow the pattern I expected. To me, it seems like using `#page_sections` (plural) would simplify the code and provide something close to what you want - eg `section = page.cards.find_by(colour: 'red')`. Without a better understanding of what the page sections being represented are, I'm not sure if it would work.

Comment: @JustinKo Added a page_section for you to look at. All of the Option cards have these elements at a minimum. The xpath is differs based off the choice selected in dropdown. So ie. if user chooses 'yellow' then all references to red in the xpath locators for the elements become 'yellow'.

Comment: @Bmoe, "All of the Option cards have these elements at a minimum" means that OptionGreenCard could have different functionality than OptionRedCard? I wish I could see the page. Seems like one crazy complex app.

Comment: @JustinKo In this case, all of the Option Cards serve the same purpose. Some just have more elements available to interact with based on user selection from a dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer to your question, is no, there is no built-in support for passing a value to the page sections. However, here are some alternatives I can think of.

**Option 1 - Use initialize_accessors**

Usually the accessors are executed at compile time. However, you could use the #initialize_accessors method to defer the execution until the initialization of the page object (or section). This would let you define your accessors in a base class that, at initialization, inserts color type into the paths:

```
class BaseCard
  include PageObject

  def initialize_accessors
    # Accessors defined with placeholder for the color type
    self.class.text_field(:field1_limit, xpath: "/html/body/some/path/#{color_type}/more/path/input")      
  end
end

# Each card class would define its color for substitution into the accessors
class OptionRedCard < BaseCard
  def color_type
    'red'
  end
end

class OptionGreenCard < BaseCard
  def color_type
    'green'
  end
end

class BasePO
  include PageObject

  page_section(:options_red_card, OptionRedCard, xpath: '/html/body/path')
  page_section(:options_green_card, OptionGreenCard, xpath: '/html/body/path')
end
```

**Option 2 - Using relative paths**

My suggested approach would be to use relative paths such that the color can be removed from the path of the page section. From the objects provided, you might be able to do something like:

```
class OptionCard
  include PageObject

  element(:unit) { following_sibling(tag_name: "#{root.tag_name}-unit") }
  div(:field1_limit) { unit_element.tr(index: 1).text_field(index: 0) }
  div(:field1_agg) { unit_element.tr(index: 1).text_field(index: 1) }
  div(:field2_limit) { unit_element.tr(index: 2).text_field(index: 0) }
  div(:field2_agg) { unit_element.tr(index: 2).text_field(index: 1) }
end

class BasePO
  include PageObject

  # Page sections only defined to the top most element of the section (the color element)
  page_section(:options_red_card, OptionCard, xpath: "/html/body/app-component/app-page/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/ngb-tabset/div/div/red")
  page_section(:options_green_card, OptionCard, xpath: "/html/body/app-component/app-page/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/ngb-tabset/div/div/green")
end
```